# CRS_Transform Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I've written below code for crs_transform extraction from sentinel2 images but it returns null value. How can I solve this problem?

```
var B5 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate('2016-01-01','2016-02-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.select('B4');


print(B5.get('crs_transform'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve crs_transform i recommend working with a single image from the collection, extracting the projection information and retrieving the crsTransform from the projection obeject, like so

`var crs_transform = B5.first().projection().transform()`

optionally and may necessarily you'll need to extract the transform as a definite value and not an object. this is(or maybe was) the case when exporting Images or reducing images by Region(s). In this case, the following will help:

`var crs_transform = B5.first().projection().getInfo().transform`

the .getInfo() forces the Earthengine to determine an object to a value in your Console. Fixes many issues with dynamic coding in the Earth Engine.